# l33t Speak translator

Tags: javascript, strings

Please review the code quality of this l33t Speak translator. Improvement suggestions are welcome. Here it is - http://jsbin.com/IHoFuQE/1

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet
  // http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/crackers.html

  var alphabets = { // common
    "a": "4",
    "b": "8",
    "e": "3",
    "f": "ph",
    "g": "6", // or 9
    "i": "1", // or |
    "o": "0",
    "s": "5",
    "t": "7" // or +
  },
    alphabets2 = { // less common
      "c": "(", // or k or |< or /<
      "d": "<|",
      "h": "|-|",
      "k": "|<", // or /<
      "l": "|", // or 1
      "m": "|\\/|",
      "n": "|\\|",
      "p": "|2",
      "u": "|_|",
      "v": "/", // or \/
      "w": "//", // or \/\/
      "x": "><",
      "y": "'/"
    };

  var words = {
    "am": "m",
    "are": "r",
    "at": "@",
    "thanks": "thx",
    "your": "ur",

    "cool": "kewl",
    "defeated": "pwned",
    "dude": "d00d",
    "fear": "ph33r", // or ph34r
    "fool": "f00",
    "freak": "phreak",
    "hacker": "h4x0r",
    "lamer": "l4m3r",
    "mad": "m4d",
    "newbie": "n00b",
    "own": "pwn",
    "phone": "fone",
    "porn": "pr0n", // or n0rp
    "rocks": "roxxorz",
    "skill": "sk1llz",
    "sucks": "sux0r",
    "the": "t3h",
    "uber": "ub3r", // or |_|83r
    "yay": "w00t",
    "yo": "j0",
    "you": "j00" // or U
  };

  var elite = document.getElementById("elite"),
    leet = document.getElementById("leet"),
    randomcase = document.getElementById("randomcase"),
    adv = document.getElementById("adv"),
    btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  function changeLetters(text) { // change letters
    text = text || elite.value.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      var alphabet = adv.checked ? alphabets[text[i]] || alphabets2[text[i]] : alphabets[text[i]];
      if (alphabet) {
        text = text.replace(text[i], alphabet);
      }
    }
    return text;
  }

  function changeWords() { // change special words and return text
    return changeLetters().replace(
      /\w+/g,
      function(word) {
        return words[word] ? words[word] : word;
      }
    );
  }

  function randomizeCase() { // RANdOMiZE CAsE
    var text = changeWords();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        text = text.replace(text[i], text[i].toUpperCase());
      } // else keep lower case
    }
    return text;
  }

  (function() { // l33t the words object
    for (var word in words) {
      if (words.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
        words[changeLetters(word)] = words[word];
        delete words[word];
      }
    }
  }());

  function tol33t() {
    leet.value = randomcase.checked ? randomizeCase() : changeWords();
  }

  elite.addEventListener("input", tol33t);
  btn.addEventListener("click", tol33t);
}());
```

Answer (score 5):

To start with, I'd like to give you credit for using `"use strict"` and limiting the scope of variables using functions.

Your `tol33t()` function is weird to me.  If the `randomcase` button is checked, you call `randomizeCase()` with no arguments.  What are you randomizing the case of?  It turns out that `randomizeCase()` calls `changeWords()`, so it turns out that the two code branches have something in common after all.  That wasn't apparent from looking at `tol33t()`.

There should be clearer separation responsibility between the DOM-interaction and text-translation layers of code.  The text translation code should reside in pure functions (whose results depend solely on their parameters) that you could call from the JavaScript console or from a unit testing engine.  That separation of concerns could be accomplished with:

```
function onTranslateButtonClicked() {
    var l33tText = toL33t(elite.value, adv.checked);
    if (randomcase.checked) l33tText = randomizeCase(l33tText);
    leet.value = l33tText;
}
```

Your "l33t the words object" initialization routine lays a trap for anyone trying to  read the code.  When code in `changeWords()` refers to the `words` associative array, one would reasonably think that it's using the definition above (i.e., `words = { "am": "m", … }`) instead of the munged version (`words = { "4m": "m" }`).  Better to make that munging explicit when you define `words` (and do so by returning a copy rather than mutating the dictionary as you iterate):

```
var words = l33tKeys({
    "am": "m",
    …
});

function l33tKeys(dict) {
    var l33tDict = {};
    for (var word in dict) {
        l33tDict[changeWord(word)] = dict[word];
    }
    return l33tDict;
}
```

I would write `changeLetters()` as:

```
 // letterSubsts may be alphabet or alphabet2
function changeLetters(text, letterSubsts) {
    return text.toLowerCase().replace(/[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letterSubsts[letter] || letter;
    });
}
```

… which is actually analogous to your implementation of `changeWords()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm having problem connecting all these. So would you please modify my jsBin.

Comment: finally I've implemented your changes, please see - http://jsbin.com/AREZoCig/2/edit?js,output

Comment: But the advanced leet wont work if I use your `changeLetters()`